# Inlining code - incompatible types: cannot infer type-variable(s) T

Tags: java

I have such piece of code:

```
 Stream<Supplier<String>> stream = Stream.of(() -> "str");
 stream.map(Supplier::get).findFirst();
```

What I naturally wanted to do was:

```
Stream.of(() -> "str").map(Supplier::get).findFirst();
```

But I got:

> incompatible types: cannot infer type-variable(s) T

and

> invalid method reference non-static method get() cannot be referenced
>   from a static context

I am puzzled, cause I thought that inlining code does not change it behavior.
What is mechanism below, that after inlining I got error?

EDIT:
Decided to add some comments to stress out what I had on mind. Let us conciser code, for example:

```
Stream<Integer> stream = Stream.of(1, 2);
stream.of(1, 2).map(i -> i * i).findFirst();
```

I can do:

```
Stream.of(1, 2).map(i -> i * i).findFirst();
```

And it is ok, so why example above (does not work)?

Comment: I get "incompatible types: cannot infer type-variable(s) T", not "invalid method reference"

Comment: It's probably because it cannot infer the type of the stream. Try `Stream.<Supplier<String>>of(() -> "str").map(Supplier::get).findFirst();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my case the line :

```
Stream.of(() -> "str").map(Supplier::get).findFirst();
```

Gives me complilation error `"The method of(() -> {}) is undefined for the type Stream"`. It gives compilation error as it unable to infer the Type. But when you are using `Stream<Supplier<String>> stream = Stream.of(() -> "str");` it automatically infer the type from the reference variable declearation. For more info about generic type inference please the [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html).

```
Stream.<Supplier<String>>of(() -> "str").map(Supplier::get).findFirst();
```

Will work as expected.

Comment: Ok, but does this code compile: `Stream<Supplier<String>> stream = Stream.of(() -> "str");
        stream.map(Supplier::get).findFirst();` -> yes. So why substituting of `stream` to `Stream.of(() -> "str")` produce error?

Comment: @Bartek It's because Java doesn't know the exact functional interface applicable to the lambda expression when you just have `Stream.of(() -> "str")` (`() -> "str"` is not allways a `Supplier<String>`, it can be any functional interface that has a `String someMethodName()` abstract method). If you assign that to a `Stream<Supplier<String>>>` variable, it does infer from that.